# AlertDialog change background color in a fragment

Tags: java, android, fragment, android-alertdialog

Good day, how can I change the background of my `AlertDialog` in `fragment`?

My `AlertDialog` will show when I click the button (fragment->button->alertdialog).

I tried the following code in implementing my `AlertDialog` and changing its background color:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle(R.string.scaleTitle);
builder.setView(R.layout.scale_layout);
builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
builder.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
```

but the background is still the same.

Please, how can I possibly change it? Thank you.

Comment: try setBackgroundDrawableResource instead of setBackgroundDrawable

Comment: @ShivamKumar I also tried the setBackgroundDrawableResource but it has no effect. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @KoralReef can you share screenshots which you want and which you get

Answer (score 0):

Define a style like this in your res-->values-->styles.xml

```
<style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/dialogColor</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/dialogWindowColor</item>
</style>
```

And create the builder by using above theme resource.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style. 
CustomAlertDialogTheme);
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#AlertDialog.Builder(android.content.Context,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below code for AlertDialog with Yellow color.

**In Java:**

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        View customTitleView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.title, null);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
        builder.setView(view);
        builder.setCustomTitle(customTitleView);
        builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
```

**In style.xml:**

```
 <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/yellow</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/yellow</item>
    </style>
```

**In colors.xml:**

```
<color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
```

**Create below layout XML:**

**title.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Dialog"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**dialog.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    Create a custom view with textview, edittext or whatever you want.

</LinearLayout>
```

**Your output will be like below image:**

[image]

I hope this is what you want to achieve, if you have any queries please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setTitle(R.string.scaleTitle);
builder.setView(R.layout.scale_layout);
builder.setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});
final AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
                @Override
                public void onShow(DialogInterface arg0) {
                alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.YELLOW));
                }
});
alertDialog.show();
```